# When I update my firebase realtime database it causes the app to enter break mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

so I'm trying to update a pet profile on my realtime database. I used break points and stepped through every single process and see that my code is able to sync with the correct profile on the database however once it does PutAsync() my emmulator enters a break mode and the data online is not updated. I'm unsure what is wrong as I'm sure I followed everything correctly.

Firebasehelper

```
public async Task<PetProfile> GetPet(string petname)
    {
        var useremail = Preferences.Get("UserSignInEmail", "");

        var PetProfiles = await GetAllPetInfos();
        await firebase
          .Child("PetProfiles")
          .OnceAsync<PetProfile>();
        return PetProfiles.Where(a => a.UserEmail == useremail && a.PetName == petname).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public async Task UpdatePet(string petname, string breed, string dob, string weight, string gender, string careinformation)
    {
        var useremail = Preferences.Get("UserSignInEmail", "");
        var toUpdatePet = (await firebase
          .Child("PetProfiles")
          .OnceAsync<PetProfile>()).Where(a => a.Object.PetName == petname && a.Object.UserEmail == useremail).FirstOrDefault();

        await firebase
          .Child("PetProfiles")
          .Child(toUpdatePet.Key)
          .PutAsync(new PetProfile() { UserEmail = useremail, PetName = petname, Breed = breed, DOB = dob, Weight = weight, Gender = gender, CareInformation = careinformation });
    }
```

editpetdetails.cs

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var pet = await firebaseHelper.GetPet(PetName);
        if (pet != null)
        {
            //update here
            await firebaseHelper.UpdatePet(
                PetNameEntry.Text, 
                BreedEntry.Text, 
                Convert.ToString(DOBEntry.Date), 
                Convert.ToString(WeightEntry.SelectedItem), 
                Convert.ToString(GenderEntry.SelectedItem),
                PetCareInfoEntry.Text);
            await DisplayAlert("Success", "Pet Profile Updated Successfully", "OK");
           

        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting an exception?  Your code does not have any exception handling

Comment: No it doesn’t have any exception handling

Comment: perhaps you should add some?

Comment: I'm getting "exception mono.debugger.soft.vm not suspended exception"

Comment: I'm also getting System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: you need to figure out which object is null, then fix it or otherwise handle it

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I spelt one of the childs wrong

Comment: @user2773611 I can not find any problem for your code, and I also find [related problem](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3495) on github, someone suggest you can try to use different Android version device or emulator to test.